# Mysql "access denied for user" error?

Tags: mysql, privileges, mysql-error-1045

I have just added a new database and imported alot of backed up data to it because of a malfunction in the previous database.

I use php and have my own Ubuntu server.

I use phpmyadmin, and have set all privileges to the user.

I am positive the password, username and host are correct.

But I still get this "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'skuffen2'"

What should I do?

Do I need to set permissions somehow on the server?

Please guide me I am in deep need of help right now...

Thanks

Comment: I recently experienced the same problem, after a restart of the machine everything worked fine. Have you tried restarting all the services or just restarting the server?

Comment: I have restarted apache2 without luck

Comment: @Camran - nothing to do with apache, u import data into `mysql` database (yes, the database name is `mysql`) and often u need to `flush privileges` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: @Camran - u restarted apache, how about `mysqld` ?

Comment: @ ajreal - want restarting the mysql service flush the privileges as well? That is why i suggested for him to restart all the services or just restart the machine.

Comment: @prolink007 - of course, restart = reload all the setting+privileges...but problem is from mysql, focus on that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login to mysql using root user, `use mysql; select * from db where user where user_name=xxx;` and check other table as well, most of the privileges settings are there, or just simply `flush privileges;`

Comment: Jeeez, thanks... But this wasn't the problem, i Solved it by deleting the entier database and importing it again... Phew