# How do I connect to remote WordPress MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want a WordPress website (let's call it "slave") to display contents from another WordPress website ("master")

I made a small plugin. It works. In Slave it Displays the local (slave) database contents.
Now I want exactly the same data in Slave but from Master.
It doesn't want to connect:
Why doesn't this work: (ofcourse it's server name etc. are fake)

```
$dbServerName = "145.77.180.15";
$dbUsername = "user_wvSuZkju";
$dbPassword = "pass3BLEx9Z";
$dbName = "database_14";
```

```
// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

I get the message

> Connection failed: Access denied for user 'user_wvSuZkju'@'server.nl' (using password: YES)

Now I also used Directadmin and set Grant to Yes for user_wvSuZkju. No change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql "access denied for user" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167915/mysql-access-denied-for-user-error)

Comment: Now i also used Directadmin and set Grant to Yes for user_wvSuZkju. No change.

Comment: it is a very, very bad idea to have a rdms open to the internet, even when you reduced the access for the user to a single ip.or in your case `reseller16.pcextreme.nl`

Comment: absolutely right. Corrected. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
In Direct Admin you have to add the ip or something to "Access host".
However ! As NBK pointed out... Granting access with an IP number is dangerous. Now i have to figure out how to grant the access safely.